# Ordered list of OR journals

Tags: optimization, academia, journals

Is there any compact resource that includes a list of all academic journals in the OR/MS space, ranked by journal importance? Although there are some helpful features offered by publisher websites such as [Elsevier journal finder](https://journalfinder.elsevier.com/), I think it would be helpful if such a list were to be added here as well.

Comment: is there a possibility to turn this thread into a public wiki and we make it such a list?

Comment: First of all, you have to decide what even constitutes an OR Journal? For instance, is "Mathematical Programming" (various series) https://link.springer.com/journal/10107 an "O.R." .journal. What about other optimization journals, some of which focus on engineering, not O.R. applications? What about applied probability journals? What about ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation (TOMACS), for which stochastic simulation and modeling applicable to O.R. is within scope, but the scope extends outside O.R/ as well?   There are plenty of other boundaries needing adjudication.

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke You are free to create a community wiki answer and encourage others to expand it. However, forcing a thread or any other posts to become CW is not recommended, see [this answer on or.meta](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/90/).

Comment: thanks for this (my suggestions wasn't meant as "forcing", apologies if it appeared that way)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are a few sources. In my opinion, all are to be taken with a grain of salt.

---

**Scimago Journal and Country Rank**

The [Scimago Journal and Country Rank](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=1803) (the link goes to the *Management Science and Operations Research* category) ranks journals according to SJR's proprietary index. The first 7 are:

[image]

To me, the rankings seem reasonable, if not totally reliable.

---

**Journal Citation Report**

When I came up for tenure about 10 years ago, my university used the *Journal Citation Report,* which at the time was owned by ISI Web of Science, but now appears to be on [a separate site](https://jcr.clarivate.com/) (but linked to from WoS). It's behind a paywall, so I can't link to the exact portion of the site (and I am finding the site quite clunky and un-user-friendly), but here is a screenshot of the first few journals listed under the *Operations Research and Management Science* category, ranked by Impact Factor:

[image]

The journals listed here are perfectly good, but I think most of us would agree that these are not the "top" 7 OR journals. (For example, *Operations Research*, *Management Science*, *Math Programming*, etc. are ranked 26, 9, and 14, respectively.) But we all also know that Impact Factor is not a terribly reliable measure of quality.

---

There is also a carefully designed, although now out of date, [article in *Interfaces*](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/inte.1050.0149) in 2005, that presents rankings of OM journals, compiled from surveys by business school professors. Here are the top 10:

[image]

Comment: Great answer Larry. Measuring the impact of the work published in various journals will always be both important and imperfect. It is too bad, though, that some schools and departments create artificial incentives/requirements to publish in certain journals. I cannot see how this helps our field, but I do understand why academic leaders believe it will help their specific units.

Answer (score 14):

Personally, I think you shouldn't be merely motivated by quantitative journal rankings as they often rely on measures that could be manipulated. In particular, the impact factor of a journal would increase if the editor required authors to cite a large number of recent publications of that journal. Although the organizations responsible for calculating these measures try to fight these tactics, there are occasional slip-ups.

Instead, I suggest that consult your senior colleagues or respected scholars in your field about this issue as top journals in OR or your field do not necessarily have the highest impact factors (a prominent example is Operations Research published by INFORMS). Ask them which journals are worth the attention or might impress the hiring committees better. This is important especially if you're working on OR-related areas such as operations management.

Finally, to complete Larry's answer, there is the "Academic Journal Guide" published by [Chartered Association of Business Schools](https://charteredabs.org), available from [here](https://charteredabs.org/academic-journal-guide-2018/). It combines quantitative measures with the opinions of experts in different fields to create a ranking list. Hence, while there is a correlation with impacts factors offered by Web of Science, the final order is not necessarily the same and offer some insights about the prestige of the journals. For example, the first OR journal in this ranking is the "Management Science" with an impact factor of about three, while the fourth journal is the "IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation" with an impact factor of about eight. I think this ranking could help you better than mere impact factors.

Answer (score 11):

Sharing the same reservations on journal rankings I can add some more which are particular relevant for hiring decisions in Germany and Europe.

The German association of business administration professors maintains the following journal rankings for different categories:

OR: https://vhbonline.org/vhb4you/jourqual/vhb-jourqual-3/teilrating-or/

OM: https://vhbonline.org/vhb4you/jourqual/vhb-jourqual-3/teilrating-prod/

Business Administration: https://vhbonline.org/vhb4you/jourqual/vhb-jourqual-3/teilrating-abwl/

Logistics: https://vhbonline.org/vhb4you/jourqual/vhb-jourqual-3/teilrating-log/

For European business schools hiring the ERIM and FT50 lists are very important:

https://www.erim.eur.nl/about-erim/erim-journals-list-ejl/

https://research.library.gsu.edu/c.php?g=388883&p=2638798

Answer (score 10):

Another source providing this information is google scholar. [Here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=phy_mathematicaloptimization) is the ranking for **mathematical optimization** journals. Also as [@Chang](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/118/chang) pointed out [here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_operationsresearch) is the ranking for operations research journals.

As per one's subject of interest; after a little search, one can get the ranking for other areas as well e.g. **game theory and decision sciences** could be found under *Business, Economics and Management* [here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=bus_gametheorydecisionscience)

Comment: Here is the ranking for OR journals from Google Scholar. 

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_operationsresearch

Answer (score 4):

There is a very new OR journal with a very broad scope:

- [SN Operations Research Forum](https://www.springer.com/business+%26+management/operations+research/journal/43069)

In addition to the journals listed in the other answers, there are some military-themed journals:

- [Military Operations Research](https://www.mors.org/Publications/MOR-Journal)
- [Journal of Defense Modeling and Simulation: Applications, Methodology, Technology](https://journals.sagepub.com/home/dms)
- [Journal of Defense Analytics and Logistics](http://www.emeraldgrouppublishing.com/services/publishing/jdal/index.htm)

These may to be good outlets for national security, defense, or other military application-themed articles.

Comment: This is useful, but the question was about finding *rankings* of journals, not just individual journals. Do you know if there is a ranking of these military OR journals?

Comment: I can post the metrics if that would help. Otherwise I can delete the answer.  I meant to include metrics but must have been distracted.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I don't know, it's really up to the OP; maybe post a comment on the question itself?