# What are the best written papers in O.R and best authors in terms of writing?

Tags: reference-request

I'm working on a paper for the first time and I would like to know which papers are recommended to study and analyze for their excellent writing and structure, and which authors in OR are recognized as strong writers.

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1163/145

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many journals offer best paper awards. For example check out the [European Journal of Operations Research best paper awards](https://www.elsevier.com/awards/European-Journal-of-Operational-Research-best-paper-awards) for some really good papers.

Answer (score 1):

The Franz Edelman award  run by informs generates a lot of interesting papers. They award a prize and also declare finalists based on impactful OR projects. Participants submit a paper as part of the process.

https://www.informs.org/Recognizing-Excellence/INFORMS-Prizes/Franz-Edelman-Award

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [How to Write about OR](https://faculty.nps.edu/gbrown/docs/Brown-%20howtowriteaboutor3.pdf) by Gerald Brown (a [NAE](https://www.nae.edu/) member).

**Full citation with free PDF:**
Brown, Gerald G. 2004. How To Write About Operations Research, *PHALANX*, Vol. 37, No. 3, p. 7. [PDF](https://faculty.nps.edu/gbrown/docs/Brown-%20howtowriteaboutor3.pdf).